# How do I retrieve only 1 row, instead of 2?

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

```
<?php
        include "connect.php";
        // Make a MySQL Connection
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment FROM comment co INNER JOIN item i WHERE co.items= i.items GROUP BY i.items"; 
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>
        No of Comments:&nbsp;<?php echo $row['comment'];?>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

it echos out like this:
Example:

No of comments:7 No of comments: 7

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: *Unrelated*: Is there a specific reason you use a non breaking space instead of just a regular space?

Comment: restrict your query to a single i.items value

Comment: What is co.items = i.items ? Is it a text or ID ?

Comment: Currently my database have 2 users who select the same items. And I tried to remove one of the user in my database, it display correctly which is No.of comments: 7. However, if 2 users or more inserted into db, it will display like No.of comments:14 etc. Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 4):

That's because you use `GROUP BY`. It means that you get the count for each distinct `i.items` in your table.

You can check by adding that items to the query results (I changed `WHERE` to `ON`):

```
SELECT 
  i.items,
  COUNT(*) AS comment 
FROM 
  comment co 
  INNER JOIN item i ON co.items = i.items 
GROUP BY 
  i.items
```

Solution is to either specify which items you want....

```
SELECT 
  i.items,
  COUNT(*) AS comment 
FROM 
  comment co 
  INNER JOIN item i ON co.items = i.items 
WHERE
  i.items = 'foo'
/* -- Grouping not needed anymore, since you only have 1 item (= 1 group)
GROUP BY 
  i.items*/
```

... or to not group, so you get the total over all items:

```
-- Will fetch the total number of comments (that are linked to an item)
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS comment 
FROM 
  comment co 
  INNER JOIN item i ON co.items = i.items
```

... or limit the results
This query just truncates the results, returning the count for only one of the items.
The item is now more or less randomly chosen, although you can add ORDER BY to influence that.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS comment 
FROM 
  comment co 
  INNER JOIN item i ON co.items = i.items 
GROUP BY 
  i.items
/* -- Optional order, if you need to influence which of the items is preffered.
ORDER BY 
  i.items*/
LIMIT 1
```

So, from you question I can only tell what the problem is, and not which solution would fit you best. But here are a couple of options to pick from. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

include "connect.php";
        // Make a MySQL Connection
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment FROM comment co INNER JOIN item i WHERE co.items= i.items GROUP BY i.items"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "No of Comments:&nbsp;". mysql_result($result, 0);

?>
```

Comment: why dod u say like "This is not an answer. 100 MINUS marks" tell me

Answer (score 0):

You could always just throw a LIMIT 1; at the end of your query, which may not be the way to structure your syntax, but without knowing what your data is, there is certainly an easy way to get the result you expect:

Replace
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment FROM comment co INNER JOIN item i WHERE co.items= i.items GROUP BY i.items";

with 
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment FROM comment co INNER JOIN item i WHERE co.items= i.items GROUP BY i.items LIMIT 1";

Comment: If he require all the 2 rows next time ? This is not about LIMIT issue. It is the problem with `GROUP By` and `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I agree Sahel, and as I stated, without knowing the use for the result, there is a number of better ways to request the data. This is a problem with the join. If he is looking for the total number of comments, irrespective of the item (which we can assume since he is grouping by item but not selecting item or referencing it in the echo statement, then he does not need to go through such trouble. I was assuming he would wrap the SQL with a WHERE statement describing which Item he wanted the comments for. Rather, he should select the item and echo the item out in a WHILE loop for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the different values of co.items and i.items. Since you are doing the group by on items, it seems likely that there are 2 different values, so each row represents the different item value

try this to debug:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment, i.items AS itemTest FROM comment co INNER JOIN item i WHERE co.items= i.items GROUP BY i.items"; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>
    No of Comments:&nbsp;<?php echo $row['comment'];?> <?php echo $row['itemTest'];?> <br />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Also do you need the join and group? What did you intend it to do? If the code is going on a page for a specific item you should be able to do

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment FROM comment co WHERE co.items= 'ITEM-IDENTIFIER-HERE' "; 
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    ?>
    No of Comments:&nbsp;<?php echo $row['comment'];?>
```

Though naturally take precautions to clean the item identifier before using it in a query, sql injection and all that